# Working with VectorLabels in GeoGraphics

Tags: geography, geographics

Consider this example of GeoGraphics:

```
$labelStyle = 
  Directive[FontFamily -> "Baskerville", 
   FontVariations -> {"CapsType" -> "SmallCaps"}, FontColor -> Orange];
Table[g = GeoGraphics[GeoZoomLevel -> 6, GeoRange -> {{40, 50}, {0, 30}}, 
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic ,
  GeoBackground -> {
    GeoStyling[{Dated["CountryBorders", year], "Border" -> Black, 
      "Ocean" -> LightBlue, "Land" -> LightYellow}],
    "VectorLabels"
    },
  ImageSize -> 400, Background -> White,
  BaseStyle -> $labelStyle (* This doesn't work *)
  ], {year, {1980, 2000}}]
```

[image]

There are a few issues with vector labels:

1. How to style them? Other than the obvious:
   `MapAt[Style[#, $labelStyle]&, g, Position[g,_Text,\[Infinity]]]`.
2. How to make them work properly with `Dated`?
3. How to add the labels for names of seas in the water?
4. How to add degree labels to the `GeoGridLines`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a brute force approach about the style.

```
$labelStyle = 
  Directive[FontFamily -> "Baskerville", 
   FontVariations -> {"CapsType" -> "SmallCaps"}, FontColor -> Orange];
Table[GeoGraphics[GeoZoomLevel -> 6, GeoRange -> {{40, 50}, {0, 30}}, 
   GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
   GeoBackground -> {GeoStyling[{Dated["CountryBorders", year], 
       "Border" -> Black, "Ocean" -> LightBlue, 
       "Land" -> LightYellow}], "VectorLabels"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   Background -> White], {year, {1980, 2000}}] /. 
 Text[a_, b__] -> Text[a, b, BaseStyle -> $labelStyle]
```

[image]

If we know the list of `GeoGridLines`, we can add degrees labels at these positions in `Epilog`. If `GeoGridLines` is Automatic, we could run it twice and use the first run to get the position of the grid lines with `AbsoluteOptions`. This is what I have done below. The position of the row (longitudes) and column (latitudes) of numbers is selected manually, but each number is placed on the correct line. We can also label the Mediterranean Sea in `Epilog`.

```
$labelStyle = 
  Directive[FontFamily -> "Baskerville", 
   FontVariations -> {"CapsType" -> "SmallCaps"}, FontColor -> Orange];
Table[gg = 
    GeoGraphics[GeoZoomLevel -> 6, GeoRange -> {{40, 50}, {0, 30}}, 
     GeoGridLines -> Automatic,
     GeoBackground -> {GeoStyling[{Dated["CountryBorders", year], 
         "Border" -> Black, "Ocean" -> LightBlue, 
         "Land" -> LightYellow}], "VectorLabels"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
     Background -> White], {year, {1980, 2000}}] /. 
  Text[a_, b__] -> Text[a, b, BaseStyle -> $labelStyle];
Table[GeoGraphics[GeoZoomLevel -> 6, GeoRange -> {{40, 50}, {0, 30}}, 
   GeoGridLines -> Automatic,
   Epilog -> {ggl = AbsoluteOptions[gg, GeoGridLines]; 
     Text[# "\[Degree]", GeoPosition[{#, 2.5}], BaseStyle -> Gray] & /@
       ggl[[1]][[2]][[1]],
     Text[# "\[Degree]", GeoPosition[{50, #}], BaseStyle -> Gray] & /@
       ggl[[1]][[2]][[2]],
Text["Mediterranean\nSea", GeoPosition[{41, 6}], BaseStyle -> Blue]
     },
   GeoBackground -> {GeoStyling[{Dated["CountryBorders", year], 
       "Border" -> Black, "Ocean" -> LightBlue, 
       "Land" -> LightYellow}], "VectorLabels"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   Background -> White], {year, {1980, 2000}}] /. 
 Text[a_, b__] -> Text[a, b, BaseStyle -> $labelStyle]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Can you make the gridline labels avoid overlapping with the lines? Also any idea on how or if we can get the appropriate country labels for the given `Dated`, e.g. yugoslavia?

Comment: You can move the labels wherever you want. For example, in the first Text in Epilog, changing ```GeoPosition[{#, 2.5}]``` to ```GeoPosition[{#+0.2, 2.5}]``` will move the latitude labels just above the grid lines. For Yugoslavia, it appears that the names of the included republics are given instead. The more recent map breaks down this area with various country borders. Note that a larger image size will reveal more labels.